# How to keep leading zeros in double type in R column

Tags: r

I need to read a bunch of zip codes into R but they have to be in double type.  I also need to keep the leading zeros for the ones that start with zero.  I tried

```
for (i in 1:length(df$region)){
  if (nchar(df$region[i])==4) {
     df$region[i] <- paste0("0", df$region[i])
  }
}
```

This converts the way I want to but it changes them all to character type and I can't read the region column into another function that requires numeric or double.  If I convert to numeric or double it gets rid of the leading zeros again.  Any ideas?

Comment: "but they have to be in double type" That seems extremely unlikely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not store them as a numeric and just add the zeros when needed through `formatC`? For example,

```
tst <- 345
class(tst)
formatC(tst, width = 5, format = "d", flag = "0")
```

gives,

```
#[1] "numeric"
#[1] "00345"
```

---

For brevity, you could even write a wrapper:

```
zip <- function(z)formatC(z, width = 5, format = "d", flag = "0")
zip(tst)
#[1] "00345"
```

And this only adds leading zeroes when needed.

```
zip(12345)
#[1] "12345"
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend keeping two columns, one in which the ZIP code appears as text, and the other as a double.  You would have to first read in the ZIP codes as character data, then create the double column from that, e.g.

```
# given df$zip_code
df$zip_as_double <- as.double(df$zip_code)
```

Double variables don't normally maintain the number of leading zeroes, because those digits are not significant anyway.  So I think storing your ZIP codes as character data is the only option here.